# Object creation optimisation

Tags: java, arrays, spring, performance, oop

I have a below piece of code :
Test class is a POJO of (id and name)

```
Test test=new Test();
Test test1=new Test();
Test test2=new Test();
for(Asset a : assets)
{
assetId=getAssetId();
test.set(assetId);
test1.set(assetId);
test2.set(assetId);
for(some loop)
{
test.set(assetName);
test1.set(assetName1);
test2.set(assetName2);

setMethod(test);
setMethod1(test1);
setMethod2(test2);

}

}
```

as we can see there's too much repetitive code. can anyone please help to optimise it?

Comment: Create a constructor that takes your fields and if you want, create a factory for constructing the object.

Comment: just wanted to add builder pattern as well into the options

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code introducing new methods helping readability and manuteneability of the code.

First define a method to generate a List of Test

```
private List<Test> createTests(int size) {
    List<Test> tests = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tests.add(new Test());
    }
    return tests;
}
```

Add a method to set the assetId on each test of a list.

```
private void setAssetId(List<Test> tests, String assetId) {
    for (Test test: tests) {
        test.set(assetId);
    }
}
```

Than you can refactoring the first part of code as

```
 List<Test> tests = createTests(3);
 for (Asset asset: assets) {
     setAssetId(tests, asset.getAssetId());
     ...
 }
```

The inner loop is not clear (it is more a pseudo code, then java code), but the idea is the same.

**If you see some duplication in your code extract a method and refactor the original code calling that method**. **The whole code will be a lot more readable** and if repetitions are many can be also smaller.

Answer (score 0):

With Lambda you can save more code.
Replace the syso with your stuff to do.

```java
package main.java.stackoverflow.oopTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test {
    
    private int id;
    
    private String name;

    public Test(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Test(int id) {
        this(id, "");
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Test> listOfTest = new ArrayList<>();
        // create your POJOS
        IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(index -> {
            listOfTest.add(new Test(index));
        });
        //iterate over your POJOS
        listOfTest.forEach(t -> System.out.println(t.id));
    }

}
```